# "List.Remove" in C# does not remove item?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hello how can i remove item from generic list here is my code im trying to do it right but i dont know where i make mistake;/

```
Users us_end = new Users();
foreach (var VARIABLE in ((List<Users>)Application["Users_On"]))
{
    if(VARIABLE.Id == (int)Session["Current_Id"])
    {
        us_end.Name = VARIABLE.Name;
        us_end.Id = VARIABLE.Id;
        us_end.Data = VARIABLE.Data;
    }
}
List<Users> us = ((List<Users>)Application["Users_On"]);
us.Remove(us_end);
Application["Users_On"] = us;
```

Comment: Well, what doesn't behave as expected? (For `Remove` to work the item needs to correctly implement `Equals`).

Comment: this doesnt really make alot of sense: you are overwriting every Users object you make inside that foreach..

Comment: Also, you cast `Application["Users_On"]` to a `List<Users`, yet later set it to a `User`.  That is obviously wrong, it can't be both if you want that code to continue "working"

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You have to get the same object to remove, not a copy.

```
Users us_end;

foreach (var VARIABLE in ((List<Users>)Application["Users_On"]))
{
    if(VARIABLE.Id == (int)Session["Current_Id"])
    {
       us_end = (Users)VARIABLE;
       break;
    }
}

if (us_end != null)
{
    List<Users> us = ((List<Users>)Application["Users_On"]);
    us.Remove(us_end);
    Application["Users_On"] = us;
}
```

**Edit:**

Just to clarify an address here, as pst pointed, you could also implement the `IEquatable` interface and some overridings like on the Groo's answer to make it work, but i think it's overkill on this specific subject. Giving this as the most common practice, but making clear that it's also possible to remove items from a list, even if they are diferent instances or even diferent objects with a technique like that.

Ref.: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187.aspx

Comment: So why haven't you posted the correct answer? if you think you are on a mood for explaining the overriding of a comparison just to remove an object from a list, do it so. I understand your pont of view, but please, make your own answer and explain it so he can mark it as the correct one instead of falling on me.

Comment: Because the answers are "correct", including this one, just [initially] misleading :) Nit: It doesn't need to implement `IEquatable` as object.Equals(object) -- remember this is polymorphic! -- can still be used. I use `Remove` and other Equals-*requiring* methods and just "expect it to work" under the equality I have defined for my types. That is, I would expect `a.Equals(b)` to work in in the same manner as `l.Add(a); l.Remove(b)` works, and vice-versa.

Answer (score 11):

By default, object equality is compared by reference in .NET (unless `Equals` is overriden, every object inherits from `object.Equals`). If you want the `Remove` method to find your object, you cannot pass a new object.

The simplest way would be to find the **actual object** which has desired properties, and then remove it:

```
var id = (int)Session["Current_Id"];
var list = (List<Users>)Application["Users_On"];  

// find the exact item to remove.
var itemToRemove = list.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == id);

// if found, remove it
if (itemToRemove != null)
{
    list.Remove(itemToRemove);
}
```

Comment: But `Equals` is virtual. This does not make sense to me.

Comment: @pst: a virtual method, unless explicity overriden, behaves like defined in the base class. `Object.Equals` compares by reference.

Comment: I can accept this after the update (it was wrong before, as the definition of Users is not known).

Answer (score 6):

You are creating a *new* `Users` object - this is not the same as any object already in `Application["Users_On"]` (it will have a different reference), so it will not be removed.

This assumes that `Equals` and/or `IEquatable<T>` were not overridden/implemented in `Users`.

```
List<Users> us = ((List<Users>)Application["Users_On"]);
Users us_end = us.Where(u => u.Id == (int)Session["Current_Id"]).FirstOrDefault();
us.Remove(us_end);
Application["Users_On"] = us;
```

By the way - your variable naming is not very good - go for more descriptive names.

Comment: Yes, it works on equality and by default for Objects, equality is implemented by checking reference ...

Comment: @pst - Which for reference type will be reference equality.

Comment: @Oded `class Users { override Equals }` ??

Comment: -1 Because this fails to address "This method determines equality using the default equality comparer EqualityComparer<T>.Default for T, the type of values in the list." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cd666k3e.aspx and "The Default property checks whether type T implements the System.IEquatable<T> interface and, if so, returns an EqualityComparer<T> that uses that implementation. Otherwise, it returns an EqualityComparer<T> that uses the overrides of Object.Equals and Object.GetHashCode provided by T." http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224763.aspx

Comment: That is, "it will have a different reference" does not imply `Remove` will not work.

Comment: @pst: a downvote usually indicates that an "answer is not useful". This is indeed the general and shortest solution to removing an item according to a specific property. You cannot always override `Equals` nor implement `IEquatable`, and even if you did, removing would always require creating the entire object (populating all properties like OP did), which is not practical.

Comment: @Groo I explained the downvote. It is misleading (and I only expect/demand the best from Oded by now :-). The implementation of `Users` is not known. I while I suspect the conclusion is correct (as with your answer), this answers fails to address `Equals` (which your answer covered in a later update).

Comment: @pst - Fair enough, though I think the assumptions that `Equals` was not overridden and that `IEquatable<T>` was not implemented are fair (nevertheless, updated answer with said assumptions).

Answer (score 0):

What's about:

```
List<Users> us = ((List<Users>)Application["Users_On"]);
Users us_end = us.First(x => x.ID == (int)Session["Current_Id"]);
us.Remove(us_end);
Application["Users_On"] = us;
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove it in place by finding the item inside the remove statement, not via an additional copy:

```
List<Users> us = ((List<Users>)Application["Users_On"]);
us.Remove(us.FirstOrDefault(u => u.ID == (int)Session["Current_Id"]));
Application["Users_On"] = us;
```

Answer (score 0):

As someone said in the previous answers: object equality is compared by reference in .NET.
But you can benefit from the difference between classes and structs by simply turning your element T inside List from class to struct.