# List.remove() not working in c#

Tags: c#, list

I am trying to remove a customer from a list, as shown below.

```
customerList.Remove(customer);
```

I display the entire list before and after this is run, and it shows that nothing is changed. I looked at another post here: ["List.Remove" in C# does not remove item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10971167/list-remove-in-c-sharp-does-not-remove-item) but I wasn't able to discern how this solution applied to mine.

I know that I need to grab the object directly from the list, and not a copy of it. I just am not sure this is the same case, and if it is I would appreciate some help!

```
string file = @"C:~\bin\Debug\Customer.xml";
List<Customer> customerList = new List<Customer> { };
XmlSerializer customerSerializer = new XmlSerializer(customerList.GetType());
using (StreamReader customerStreamReader = new StreamReader(file))
{
    customerList = (List<Customer>)customerSerializer.Deserialize(customerStreamReader);
}
Console.WriteLine();
customerList.Remove(customer);
```

Comment: I can't view the chat link at work :( please give me the help back!

Comment: Can you put it in a pastebin for me

Comment: Will I get fired if I ask?